# Android Studio - Get content with original format

Tags: java, kotlin

Is there a way I could fetch data from an excel file but keep the data in an original format such as color and font size? The issue I ran into was that some of the data are equal in value but I don't want all of them to have the same formation. I did create some conditions using an Adapter but it changes all data of the same value across the class and I don't need that.

Comment: Your question is lacking basic information like for example what library you use for reading the excel table and the relevant code parts you use for extracting data from the excel file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.